# Run "rvm alias create default 2.0" command?

Tags: ruby, rvm, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a Chef recipe which installs RVM and Ruby. in the recipe I am using the `execute` resource to run the following command:

```
rvm alias create default 2.0
```

but this does not set my default Ruby version to 2.0. If I run this command directly on the host it does work because when I type `ruby -v` the version is set to 2.0 but when I try to run it through the Chef recipe `ruby -v` still returns 1.8.

This is my resource declaration:

```
execute "set_ruby_to_version_#{version}" do
    command "rvm alias create default #{version}"
    action :run
end
```

How come it doesn't work through the Chef recipe? I know that there is a cookbook available to deal with RVM but I still want to know why this is not working.

Comment: May be because you run the command as your user, but Chef runs is as root?

Answer (score 1):

since rvm 1.25 rvm does not create wrappers in `$rvm_path/bin` if you depend on this wrappers (it's already in your `PATH`) then run this after creating alias:

```
rvm wrapper default --no-prefix
```

if you need a wrapper for specific gem add it's name after the command, ex:

```
rvm wrapper default --no-prefix haml
```

it will create only this wrapper: `$rvm_path/bin/haml`

other approach would be adding the automatically generated wrappers to `PATH`:

```
PATH=$rvm_path/gems/ruby-2.1.0/wrappers:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rvm alias create default 2.1.2
rvm use 2.1.2
```

Works for me.